# AWS Amplify API export error on app start

Tags: angular, amazon-web-services, graphql, aws-amplify, aws-sdk-js

I set up my amplify/angular project and add the GraphQL service to the app.

Like in the amplify doc I add the following to the main.ts

```
import API from '@aws-amplify/api';
  API.configure(awsconfig);
```

and after that I get the following error on starting the app (ng serve):

```
ERROR in ./node_modules/@aws-amplify/api/lib-esm/API.js 194:4-11
"export 'Amplify' was not found in '@aws-amplify/core'
```

package.json

```
    {
   "name": "web-template",
   "version": "0.0.0",
   "scripts": {
     "ng": "ng",
     "start": "ng serve",
     "build": "ng build",
     "test": "ng test",
     "lint": "ng lint",
     "e2e": "ng e2e"
   },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "~10.0.0",
    "@angular/common": "~10.0.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "~10.0.0",
    "@angular/core": "~10.0.0",
    "@angular/forms": "~10.0.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "~10.0.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "~10.0.0",
    "@angular/router": "~10.0.0",
    "@aws-amplify/api": "^3.1.17",
    "@aws-amplify/auth": "^2.1.8",
    "@aws-amplify/core": "^2.3.0",
    "@aws-amplify/pubsub": "^2.1.9",
    "@aws-amplify/ui-angular": "^0.2.9",
    "@aws-amplify/xr": "^1.1.8",
    "@react-native-community/netinfo": "^5.9.4",
    "aws-amplify": "^3.0.18",
    "core-js": "^3.6.5",
    "rxjs": "~6.5.5",
    "tslib": "^2.0.0",
    "zone.js": "~0.10.3"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "^0.1000.0",
    "@angular/cli": "~10.0.0",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "~10.0.0",
    "@angular/language-service": "~10.0.0",
    "@types/jasmine": "~3.5.11",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.3",
    "@types/node": "~14.0.14",
    "jasmine-core": "~3.5.0",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~5.0.2",
    "karma": "^5.1.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~3.1.0",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "~3.0.3",
    "karma-jasmine": "~3.3.1",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^1.5.4",
    "protractor": "^7.0.0",
    "ts-node": "~8.10.2",
    "tslint": "~6.1.2",
    "typescript": "~3.9.5"
  }
}
```

Pls can anybody explain what the problem is?

Thx a lot

Comment: did you managed to find solution?

Comment: Not really sry. I ve just re-installed dependencies and tried around a lot... and finaly it works.... bur I really dont know what the exat problem was...